# How to Import many files to an Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I want to make a scheduled flow to reading a directory includes CSV files and import them to a Oracle table (I don't know the file names), I've tried ODI (using variables) but ODI needs to know the file_name and if I create a table for the file_names for using with ODI variables, as the daily total files is over 200,000, it may caused problems whether files comes with delay or missed one.
It's appreciated if you could lead me into this matter.

Comment: just to clarify, you get over 200,000 separate files per day?

Comment: I would do it with java...

Comment: yes ,actually every 10 minutes i'll receive about 250 separated files

Comment: seems nobody can help me :(